# Android Buttons in Code same size

Tags: android, button, dynamic, size

I want to add buttons dynamically and to have them same sizes. Buttons count depends on length of a word. It looks quite allright when I have long word:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ3FS.jpg

But when I have only 1 letter as a word it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyYhd.jpg

This is my code:

```
 public void loadButtons() {
    buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons_Layout);
    answerButtons = new Button[word.length()];


    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        answerButtons[i] = new Button(this);
        answerButtons[i].setText(null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f); 
        answerButtons[i].setLayoutParams(Params1);


        answerButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        buttonsLayout.addView(answerButtons[i]);
    }
```

How could I achieve that? :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky solution, hope it works

```
public void loadButtons() {
    buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons_Layout);
    answerButtons = new Button[word.length()];

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (word.length() == 1) ? new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) : new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f);


for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    answerButtons[i] = new Button(this);
    answerButtons[i].setText(null);
    answerButtons[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    answerButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    buttonsLayout.addView(answerButtons[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. :) Nevertheless it doesn't fix my problem completely. If I would run it on bigger screen with for instance 3 letters word it would get shaggy again. Something like this: http://i58.tinypic.com/2zqct2w.jpg  ... Is it absolute size? It wouldn't fit on small displays if I give it absolute size.

Comment: On the image, the top 3 letter are possibly absolute on size, but the bottom of the image I presume is a nested linearlayout with two rows. How many letters are you going to ne using? What do you want to happen when there are too many for the screen, so I can try to make a more dynamic solution.